# Sorry, your request could not be processed as it contained an invalid security token on app install

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm developing application and recently me and some customers faced issue installing/uninstalling apps (both draft and live) "Sorry, your request could not be processed as it contained an invalid security token. Please refresh and try again".  Refresh doesn't help and I'm not getting any info on my server. Is there any fix?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your application, we can't Guess the server type, application language

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer from BC team. There's nothing to do with my application - it's cookies issue on BC side. Tried another browser in incognito mode and it worked

Comment: this also worked for me, switching from chrome to firefox worked, chrome incognito did not work